# npm vs Apache build tools(maven, ant, groovy)

Tags: maven, groovy, ant, npm

I have come across npm(Node Package Manager) which is used to share the code between js developers. Since this can be achievable through the existing build tools from Apache.
 What is the difference between npm(Node Package Manager) and Apache build tools(Ant, Maven, Groovy)?

Answer (score 1):

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) is a package manager, designed to download code that other developers write and you want to share.

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) are Java build tools designed to compile Java source code and turn it into a jar file that can be run. In a modern open source world we don't write all our own source code, so [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) pioneered the idea of also managing the jars that other developers write, which links with our code.

Lastly [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) is a Java based programming language.